# Check if html element is overlaying another element of a different z-index with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a hamburger nav element that is white most of the site has a dark background, but a couple of sections have light backgrounds.

What im trying to do is if the hamburger nav is over one div keep its css one way, if its over another div change its css.

Ive been trying to get this to work by calculating how much the page has scrolled using `$document.scrollTop()` and there by working out where the hamburger nav would be, but there a 2 issues with this :

1) its not very automated and each time new content is added to the page and the sections get longer it will have to be recalculated

2) Some of the section heights are set responsibly so knowing the height of section in advance and the hamburgers position in relation to them is not possible.

Any idea how this could be done ?

Ive made a JSfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/kd1x7jk4/1/

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are describing is collision detection.

There is a library that can help here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/